# Extjs Using Radio Buttons with getFieldValues

Tags: extjs

I'm having trouble submitting radio button values. I have two radio buttons set up like this:

```
{
xtype: 'radio',
fieldLabel: 'Employment Type',
boxLabel: 'Documented',
name: 'employment_type',
checked: true,
inputValue: 'documented'
},
{
xtype: 'radio',
boxLabel: 'Contracted',
name: 'employment_type',
inputValue: 'contracted'
}
```

I am submitting the form this way using an AJAX call.

```
var myParams = { 
employee: form.getFieldValues()
}   

Ext.Ajax.request({
url: '/employees',
jsonData: myParams,
success: function(result, request){
...
```

In the server console I see the parameter passed as shown below, which is wrong.

```
"employment_type"=>[false, true]
```

How I'd like to have the parameter passed:

```
"employment_type"=>"documented"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `form.getForm().getValues()` instead of `form.getFieldValues()` as illustrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisramakers/eL7qg/

But on another note, why aren't you submitting by just calling `form.getForm().submit()` and let Ext.form.BasicForm handle all the data gathering?

Comment: this worked thanks, i am setting some other params inside myParams, not using Ext.form.BasicForm cause there is a formatting issue with the JSON when using 2 params.